# image on click change image and call function

Tags: javascript, sorting, onclick

I have a xhtml page where i display a table, this table has to be sorted in asc and desc order. initially i show an img called 01 now on clicking this 01 my image has to change to 02 while also sorting the table ascendingly for which i have written js code in external .js file. Now if i again click on the  image 02 it should change to 03 by calling the function descending in external .js file.

**my xhtmlcode**

```
 <center>
     PAID IMPRESSIONS 
     <input type="image" id="table_sorter" src="../img/up-down.png" onclick="sort_imp()" />
 </center>
```

**my javascript code to change image and call another function**

```
 function sort_imp() {

            if (document.getElementById("table_sorter").src === "../img/up-down.png")
            {
                document.getElementById("table_sorter").src = "../img/view-sort_ascending.png"
               sorting_imp_asc();

            }
            else if (document.getElementById("table_sorter").src === "../img/view_sort_ascending.png")
            {
                document.getElementById("table_sorter").src = "../img/view_sort_descending.png";
               sorting_imp_des();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, JavaScript gives image-URL from root, and hence can't be compared with `../img/....` format.
i.e. `document.getElementById("table_sorter").src === "../img/up-down.png"`

**Instead you can try like `indexOf()`:**

```
function sort_imp() {
        /*copies full img path to a string*/
        var str = document.getElementById("table_sorter").src;

        /*check that, img path contains required string*/
        if (str.indexOf("img/up-down.png")>=0) {
            document.getElementById("table_sorter").src = "../img/view-sort_ascending.png"
            sorting_imp_asc();

        }
        else if (str.indexOf("img/view-sort_ascending.png")>=0) {
            document.getElementById("table_sorter").src = "../img/view-sort_descending.png";
            sorting_imp_des();
        }

    }
```